# show the sucess popup after form submit form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, codeigniter

Here i added one form with data model in codeigniter views page

```
<a class="handCursor "  href="javascript:void(0)" id="franchise">Franchisee </a>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="franchisee_signup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>general/general_form" method="POST" name="signup">
            <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
               <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> Request For Franchisee Program</h4>
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            <div class="modal-body clearfix">
               <div class="bk_lft" style="width:100%;">
                  <div class="bk_gr" style="width:100% !important">
                     <div class="contact_form2">
                        <div class="bk_roominfo">
                           <div class="clearfix"></div>
                           <div class="frm_clmn">
                              <label>First Name: <em style="color:#F00;">*</em></label>
                              <input name="first_name" id="txt_name" type="text">
                              <input name="form_type" id="company_name" type="hidden" value="franchise">
                           </div>
                           <div class="frm_clmn1">
                              <label>Last Name: <em style="color:#F00;">*</em></label>
                              <input name="last_name" id="txt_lname" type="text">
                           </div>
                           <div class="frm_clmn">
                              <label>Phone: <em style="color:#F00;">*</em></label>
                              <input name="mobile" id="txt_mobile" type="text">
                           </div>
                           <div class="frm_clmn1">
                              <label>Email: <em style="color:#F00;">*</em></label>
                              <input name="email" id="txt_email" type="text">
                           </div>
                           <div class="frm_clmn1" style="width:100%;">
                              <label>Message:<em style="color:#F00;">*</em></label>
                              <textarea name="message" id="txt_message" cols="" rows="" style="resize:none;"></textarea>
                           </div>
                           <div class="bk_bt" style="float:left; margin-top:12px;">
                              <button type="submit" name="send_contact_enq" id="send_contact_enq" value="Continue" style="float:left;">Send</button>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is the form  and we add the insert query in controller

```
public function general_form()
{
    $post = $this->input->post();
    unset($post['send_contact_enq']);
    $insert_id = $this->custom_db->insert_record('corporate_form_reqlist',$post);
    redirect(base_url()."general/index");
}
```

after submitting the form while inserting into `db` and we redirect to front page . we need before redirect from controllers is there is any possible to show the success popup after close the popup message redirect happened .

we tried all my logic which i know but not get the correct response

Comment: using flashdata you pass data.see....https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: i tried that one also
$this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'Request set to Admin. Admin get back you ASAP');
but it wont get

Comment: If you are able to popup success message on click of ok or close button just add this `window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";`

Comment: no bihola problem for popup message only

Comment: you means after redirect page you need to open popup?

Comment: In that case you have to submit your form using ajax.

Comment: You just need to popup success if the `insert_record` is successful and then redirect the user after closing the pop up?

Comment: no nikhil same as set_flashdata only i need but set_flashdata not working in my project .is there any alternative for set_flashdata

Comment: yes momouu i want popup success if the insert_record is successful

Comment: i tried ajax call also but its didnt get the full form data

Comment: Show your full source code what you try so far.

Comment: i didnt get you nikhil. you want that ajax call of source code???

Comment: Then try to figure out a way to submit full form data using ajax call.

Comment: What is the value returned to `$insert_id` if it is successful?

Comment: insert record value

Comment: I have edited my answer, check it if it works

Comment: not working momuu

Comment: try again. I have edited it

Comment: no momouu . in controller script will not acceptef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($insert_id=='success'){//change success based on the returned value of the model
    echo "<script>
        alert('Success');
        window.location.href='".base_url('general/index')."';
        </script>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try passing some value as param and give success message by checking that in redirected page..

```
 redirect(base_url()."general/index?status=success");
```

and in general/index file

```
 if(isset($_GET['status']) && $_GET['status'] == "success"){
       echo "Successfull Message";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax function for your form that will send data to PHP to execute general_form tasks without redirecting. PHP returns true if successfully inserts record to db and javascript then triggers alert() or prompt() and windows.location = "your redirection link"